# WCF DataContract inheritance

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I have WCF with `DataContract` defined and a few other `DataContract` that extend it. So it looks something like this in it's primitive form:

```
    [DataContract(Name = "FacilityPerson"]
    [KnownType(typeof(Student))]
    [KnownType(typeof(Teacher))]
    public class Person
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }   

    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Student
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
        public int StudentID { get; set; }

    }

[DataContract]
public class Teacher
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
    public int StaffID { get; set; }

}
```

I have a `ServieContract` that has only one operation and looks like this:

```
[OperationContract(Name = "ReportNewPerson")]
void ReportNewTeacherOrStudent(Person person);
```

My problem is when I am implementing it, I can't access children properties of a parent object.

```
public class UniversityService : IUniversityServiceContract  
{

        void ReportNewTeacherOrStudent(Person person)
        {
             if(person.GetType().FullName == "Student")
             {
                     //here I have a parent object so I cannot getStudentId which is a child property           
                     Console.Writeline(person.StudentId);

             }

        }
}
```

What should I do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't compare the type from the name; instead, use a cast or the `as` operator to do that:

```
public class UniversityService : IUniversityServiceContract  
{
    public void ReportNewTeacherOrStudent(Person person)
    {
        Student student = person as Student;
        if (student != null)
        {
            Console.Writeline(student.StudentId);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check carlosfigueira's answer. He is right.

You also need to add inheritance for your `Teacher` and `Student` classes:

```
[DataContract]
public class Student: Person
{
    ...
}

[DataContract]
public class Teacher: Person
{
   ...    
}
```

Update: Yes, you have to specify attributes in both parent and children.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yeah, I have it in a code just forgot it here.

Comment: Do attributes inherit? Are the necessary on the subclasses (or is that just good for readability)?